# pushing arrays in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, multidimensional-array

I want to push arrays containing random numbers (0 to 10) into a bigger array once the total of its contents is about to exceed 30. But the output is messed up.

```
var bigarray = new Array();
var smallarray = new Array();

var randNum = 0;
var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i<10; i++){

    randNum = (10*Math.random()).toFixed(0);
    total = total + randNum;


    if(total>30) {

        bigarray.push(smallarray)

        smallarray.length=0;
        smallarray.push(randNum);
        total = randNum;

    } else {

        smallarray.push(randNum);

    }

}

alert(" BIG ARRAY IS "+bigarray);
```

Comment: when you make randNum toFixed it becomes a string...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to you code and came up with this.

```
var bigarray = [];
var smallarray = [];

var randNum = 0;
var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    randNum = Math.floor(10 * Math.random()); // you will never have a value of 10?
    total = total + randNum;

    if (total > 30) {
        bigarray.push(smallarray.slice())
        smallarray.length = 0;
        smallarray.push(randNum);
        total = randNum;
    } else {
        smallarray.push(randNum);
    }
}

alert(" BIG ARRAY IS " + bigarray);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5VbhV/)

Things I changed were:

Ran the code through a [beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Changed your use of `new Array` to `[]`

> {} and []
>
> Use {} instead of new Object(). Use [] instead of new Array().
>
> Because Object and Array can be overwritten by the user

Changed `++` to `+= 1`

> This pattern can be confusing.

Check out [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) and [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Added [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) when you push `smallarray` to `bigarray`, this makes a copy in this case. It is important to understand how javascript works, read [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) Without using slice, which makes a copy as the array only contains primitives, when you set the length of the array to 0, then the data was lost.

Changed your use of [number.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) so that randNum remains a number

Note: [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1] that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive)

Whether your code now produces your expected out, I can not be sure from your description but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: it was awesome! thanks a ton. so, what happens when you use push instead of slice  with arrays ? does 'push' act differently when it comes to arrays ?

Comment: I updated the answer with link and some further explanation to try an clarify the situation for you.

Answer (score 0):

two wrong things are visible on the first sight in the code

**(1)** instead of

```
randNum = (10*Math.random()).toFixed(0);
```

you probably want

```
randNum = Math.floor(11*Math.random());
```

- Math.floor instead of toFixed() - see @kennebec comment
- 11 instead of 10 to return numbers 0 to 10, as `0 <= Math.random() < 1`

**(2)** the following line pushes (many times) the reference to the same smallarray object.

```
bigarray.push(smallarray);
```

In the next step you clear the array with `smallarray.length = 0`. Because the array is not copied to the bigarray, but only referenced, the generated items are lost.

**EDIT: I read your question wrong - the rest of the answer is fixed**

You probably want to push the duplicate of the smallarray into bigarray, so replace the line above with the following:

```
bigarray.push(smallarray.slice(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var bigarray = new Array();
    var smallarray = new Array();
    var randNum = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < smallarray.length; j++) {
            total = total + smallarray[j];
        }
        if (total <= 30)
        { 
            randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            smallarray.push(randNum);
        }
        else {
            bigarray.push(smallarray.slice(0));                
            smallarray.length = 0;
        }
        total = 0;    

    }
    alert(" BIG ARRAY IS " + bigarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another loop inside the main one to populate the smallarray, something like:

```
var bigarray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i<10; i++){

    // moving the variable declarations inside this loop means they are re-set for each small array
    var smallarray = new Array();
    // create the first entry for the small array
    var randNum = Math.floor(11*Math.random());
    var total = randNum;

    // loop to populate the small array
    while(total <= 30){
        smallarray.push(randNum);
        randNum = Math.floor(11*Math.random());
        total += randNum;
    }
    bigarray.push(smallarray)
}
```